# Maven tell plugin to not run during phase

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there any phase I can use to prevent Maven from running a plugin goal or any other way I can tell Maven to skip a plugin goal?
Basically, I want to just run it manually.

```
 <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase >pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wget</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/output</outputDirectory>
        <url>http://some.url</url>
        <outputFileName>filename</outputFileName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I use pre-integration-test it runs during mvn install. However, I just want to run it manually.

Comment: Can you show an example what you like to run only run on cli ?

Comment: The main way to achieve this would be to use profiles, which you manually activate. While another option would be to use the phase `none` while defining the plugin in your pom. This would stop it from being executed by default and then you could call the plugin explicitly.

Comment: The phase "none" was exactly what I was looking for. If you put that as an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Phase `none` worked for my scenario to keep test-jars from being created for specific modules in my multi-module maven project. Like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-jar</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```